# Service call isms with ADB shell (Android SDK)?

Tags: android, shell, sdk, sms, adb

Do you know the command "service call isms" with adb shell on Android?
Here is the complete command I use : service call isms 5 s16 "PhoneNumber" i32 0 i32 0 s16 "BodyText".

There are some parameter but I don't know what it means (5, s16, i32, 0). Is there somewhere a manual ?
The most important for me is to get an error when the sms doesn't send successfully (about 10% of the sms aren't send) => this question asked already but there isn't answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17395546/get-status-sms-from-isms-service-using-shell-adb-android-sdk).

I don't wanna use the commands
(adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.SENDTO -d sms:CCXXXXXXXXXX --es sms_body "SMS BODY GOES HERE" --ez exit_on_sent true
adb shell input keyevent 22
adb shell input keyevent 66)
because it uses the graphical interface.

Could you help me? (I'm sorry, I can't speak English. So, I hope you understand my request)

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 7):

In every "service call" command, you need to enter:

- the service you want to call, in this case it is "isms";
- the "function" you want to call, in this case it is "5" (more about that later);
- the function parameters.

There's two types of possible parameters: **Strings** and **Integers**. Before entering an Integer parameter you need to specify its type using **i32**.
Same thing for a String parameter, but instead you need to write **s16**.

Most of the "service call" commands have no documentation, or very little.
For the ISms you can look here: http://www.androidjavadoc.com/1.0_r1_src/constant-values.html
to get a list of the possible functions and their number code. Hit ctrl-f and enter ISms for quick access.

The "5" function for the ISms service is the **sendMultipartText** function from the ISms interface of the Android API. [Here is the doc about this function.](http://www.androidjavadoc.com/1.0_r1_src/com/android/internal/telephony/gsm/ISms.html#sendMultipartText%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.util.List,%20java.util.List,%20java.util.List%29) [And here is the implementation class from the API.](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/com/android/internal/telephony/ISms.java/?v=source)

So, `service call isms 5 s16 "PhoneNumber" i32 0 i32 0 s16 "BodyText"`, equals:

> Call the sendMultipartText function from the ISms service with the
>   String parameter "PhoneNumber", the Integer parameter 0, the Integer
>   parameter 0 and the String parameter "BodyText".

**To answer your question**, I am pretty sure there's no way to know if the sms are being sent or not from the command line... But maybe if you dig a little deeper than I did in the API you'll find a way.

Comment: the link http://www.androidjavadoc.com/1.0_r1_src/constant-values.html  has metamorphosed into 404 and flew away

Comment: In addition to that, `sendMultipartText` simply doesn't exist anymore on recent versions of Android. There is [sendMultipartTextForSubscriber](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/c69f445dc10b63e52f019aaafcb816293987935d/telephony/java/com/android/internal/telephony/ISms.aidl#L282) now, but it take way more parameters.