# ADB Command to set volume?

Tags: android, adb

Is there any Adb command to set the volume to a particular value? I know that we can do

```
adb shell input keyevent
```

for volume up and down but i want to set it to a particular value. If I change it it DB then I have to reboot the device for the changes to be reflected so i do not want to go that path. Isn't there any API where I can change the value without having to restart it and having to be dependent on Volume up and Down?

Answer (score 18):

`media` shell command can also be used:

```
media volume:  the options are as follows: 
    --stream STREAM selects the stream to control, see AudioManager.STREAM_*
                    controls AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC if no stream is specified
    --set INDEX     sets the volume index value
    --adj DIRECTION adjusts the volume, use raise|same|lower for the direction
    --get           outputs the current volume
    --show          shows the UI during the volume change
examples:
    adb shell media volume --show --stream 3 --set 11
    adb shell media volume --stream 0 --adj lower
    adb shell media volume --stream 3 --get
```

The first example is probably the one you were looking for (but it probably didn't exist at the time of asking)

Comment: just to improve the last sentence of this answer: "media" command does not have "volume" subcommand e.g. on Marshmallow


`bash# adb shell media
usage: media [subcommand] [options]
       media dispatch KEY
       media list-sessions
       media monitor <tag>
[...]`

Comment: @amonthedeamon, I just tried it, my adb definitely has this volume subcommand listed just after the `media monitor <tag>` I have a `media volume [options]`. Maybe It depends on the android version of the device; I only have an android 9 to test.

Comment: On a Google Pixel 3a with Android 12 installed, the `media` command does not seem to exist. Calling `adb shell media` on a cmd gives me `/system/bin/sh: media: inaccessible or not found`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

This is an answer for anyone whose Android is too old to have `volume` subcommand in `media` command.

Thanks to Alex P's link, I got the inspiration from this guy's blog:
http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/09/calling-android-services-from-adb-shell.html

You can use `service` command to call functions like `void setStreamVolume(int streamType, int index, int flags, String callingPackage)` on your Android device - a [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20227326/where-to-find-info-on-androids-service-call-shell-command).
Tried with my un-rooted Android 5.1 device and it worked.

```
Usage: service [-h|-?]
       service list
       service check SERVICE
       service call SERVICE CODE [i32 INT | s16 STR] ...
Options:
   i32: Write the integer INT into the send parcel.
   s16: Write the UTF-16 string STR into the send parcel.
```

But the `CODE` differs between Android versions. To find the code for `setStreamVolume()`, first save the Bash script from [this gist](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ktnr74/ac6b34f11d1e781db089/raw/e32065b70058864294dcd2466958c1d02b32286b/get_android_service_call_numbers.sh), change its permission to executable, connect your device via ADB and run the script with `audio` as argument:

```
$ ./get_android_service_call_numbers.sh audio
```

(EDIT: https://github.com/T-vK/android-svc does that script.)

The script pulls info from Google and show you a list like [this](https://gist.github.com/ReeseWang/3a03cc32f727064b5918b318d14beb64).

So we know the code for `setStreamVolume()` is 4, since we know [the number for `STREAM_MUSIC` is 3](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager#STREAM_MUSIC), we can set music volume to 7 by this command:

```
$ adb shell service call audio 4 i32 3 i32 7
```

The maximum music volume on my device is `0xF`, you can query yours with `int getStreamMaxVolume(int streamType)` function:

```
$ adb shell service call audio 15 i32 3
```

Answer (score 5):

For those of you struggling with the answer provided by XioRCal, use `adb shell cmd media_session` instead of `adb shell media` as it has been removed in Android 11 and 12.

Reference: ["media: inaccessible or not found" error when attempting to control device volume via ADB](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/246659/media-inaccessible-or-not-found-error-when-attempting-to-control-device-volum)

Comment: Posted it as a separate answer since I cannot comment.

Answer (score 4):

On a rooted phone you can call `setMasterVolume()` with `service call audio <code> i32 <volume>`. The codes are version specific. Let's say you want to set volume to 50% on a KitKat device. The command will be:

```
service call audio 9 i32 50
```

Comment: How about on jelly bean would the code be the same? I have tried setting the volume on a jelly bean device using this method and it doesn't seem to work?

Comment: read http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/09/calling-android-services-from-adb-shell.html to find out the proper code for your android version

Answer (score 4):

I have used the service call audio test to set the volume on an android 2.3 device. In order to be more generic you need to research IBinder and the transaction number.

To find out what you want:

Adb shell service list packages

- this will tell you the package file you need to look at for a service (I.e Bluetooth - com.Bluetooth.IBluetooth)

Search for the service class and 'transaction' online ("com.Bluetooth.Ibluetooth transaction")

Find the source files and find the Ibinder transaction details. This will be followed by the details of the input parameters.

I.e the first transaction on Bluetooth is .is enabled(). There are no input parameters

To use it send:

Adb shell service call Bluetooth 1

It should return a parcel containing the answer.

Remember:
  - I think it is only for rooted devices
  - the transaction number you find has an offset of 1 (transaction 0 is called with service call 'service' 1)
  - There are two types of input: i32 for integer or s16 for string

To set the audio there are three input integers for set volume (transaction 6)

To use it send:

Adb shell service call 7 i32 3 i32 15 i32 0
This will set the media volume to 15 (default number of levels for media audio is 15)

Answer (score 0):

In android 12 or later, can use `cmd media_session` shell cmd.
below is the usage: (need replace some `media` to `cmd media_session`)

```
usage: media_session [subcommand] [options]
       media_session dispatch KEY
       media_session dispatch KEY
       media_session list-sessions
       media_session monitor <tag>
       media_session volume [options]

media_session dispatch: dispatch a media key to the system.
                KEY may be: play, pause, play-pause, mute, headsethook,
                stop, next, previous, rewind, record, fast-forword.
media_session list-sessions: print a list of the current sessions.
media_session monitor: monitor updates to the specified session.
                       Use the tag from list-sessions.
media_session volume:  the options are as follows: 
                --stream STREAM selects the stream to control, see AudioManager.STREAM_*
                                controls AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC if no stream is specified
                --set INDEX     sets the volume index value
                --adj DIRECTION adjusts the volume, use raise|same|lower for the direction
                --get           outputs the current volume
                --show          shows the UI during the volume change
        examples:
                adb shell media volume --show --stream 3 --set 11
                adb shell media volume --stream 0 --adj lower
                adb shell media volume --stream 3 --get
```