# Can I completely mute the phone using ADB?

Tags: android, adb

I would like to turn off all the sounds on my Android device, using ADB.

Is that possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21059714/1778421

Comment: For the record, I think the close decision is wrong. Not only is ADB a programming tool (the D stands for Debugging), it is often used within a script to automatically test apps (that's how I got here). In this specific case it's very likely to be the case, as most people won't bother muting via ADB when they can just click on the device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run  "adb shell input keyevent 25" multiple times in a batch file

Comment: I think will be better to call: adb shell input keyevent 164

Comment: For reference: `25 KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN`, `164 KEYCODE_VOLUME_MUTE`. Source: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN

Answer (score 9):

In a terminal run:

```
adb shell input keyevent 164
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be to make an app that you install on the phone which can receive an intent sent via `adb` and then have the app do the muting.