# ADB shell command to cancel and remove all jobs in my app

Tags: android, adb, android-jobscheduler, dumpsys

With improper enquing jobs, there can be easily mess, is there any adb command to remove all pending and active jobs (showed by `adb shell dumpsys jobscheduler`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call `JobScheduler.cancelAll()` via `adb` use:

```
adb shell service call jobscheduler 5
```

For finer control use `JobScheduler.cancel(int jobId)`:

```
adb shell service call jobscheduler 4 i32 <jobId>
```

To confirm the proper `service call` codes for your Android version read

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25987165/1778421

Comment: How to get the JobId ??

Answer (score 1):

Jobs cancelling support was recently added to ADB, can be invoked using `cmd jobscheduler` command.

Sample execution:

```
$ adb shell cmd jobscheduler cancel com.my.packagename  
Canceling all jobs for com.my.packagename in user 0
```

The command documentation says the following (copied from a device running Android 11):

```
  cancel [-u | --user USER_ID] PACKAGE [JOB_ID]
    Cancel a scheduled job.  If a job ID is not supplied, all jobs scheduled
    by that package will be canceled.  USE WITH CAUTION.
    Options:
      -u or --user: specify which user's job is to be run; the default is
         the primary or system user
```