# Phone number via adb

Tags: android, adb

The question is simple. How do I get my phone number via adb. It's not listed in getprop. I guess it's possible to find it under service or settings but i didn't found it. It's a Huawei device with android 8.0 installed.

Comment: there is a type of sim cards, which don't provide the phone number to the phone, so there is a chance that you simply can't get it on some sim cards

Comment: Ok, i am able to see the number under contacts if i check on my personal info.

Comment: Still trying to find a good way for this wtihout root. Foor root devices all simcard data can be found in: sqlite3 -line /data/user_de/0/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/telephony.db 'select * * from siminfo' or from carrier..The phone number is masked with asterix in dumpsys/logcat, another way i s to use tcpdump for sniff the rmnet interface but this is rly to complicated, looking for something more elegant

Answer (score 1):

This might work in some cases.

```
adb shell service call iphonesubinfo 13
```

By running this command I am calling getLine1Number method.
[This](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-cts-8.0_r15/telephony/java/com/android/internal/telephony/IPhoneSubInfo.aidl) is the aidl file I am referring to.
To know more about adb service command read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20227326/where-to-find-info-on-androids-service-call-shell-command/53198696#53198696)

To know the reason why it will not work in other cases, refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134398/telephonymanager-getline1number-failing/5134725#5134725).

Comment: This prints IMEI number.

Comment: Edited it. Actually getLine1Number was the 13th line in the aidl file.