# Obtaining MSISDN from from Android using ADB

Tags: android, adb

I would like to obtain the MSISDN from a Google Nexus phone running Android 4.4.4.

I found this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20227326/where-to-find-info-on-androids-service-call-shell-command) answer very informative for how to make sense of Android service calls and I believe I now have the correct service command given [this .aidl](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-4.4.4_r2.0.1/telephony/java/com/android/internal/telephony/IPhoneSubInfo.aidl).

```
adb shell service call iphonesubinfo 8
```

However I don't know how to parse the response I'm getting...?

```
Result: Parcel(00000000 00000000 00000000  '............')
```

Any advice appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

1. The aidl link you've attached is an interface, but not all the manufacturers fully implement it.
2. It also depends on the Android version - in my device, calling service #8 results with the IMSI number of the sim card and not the msisdn.