# Changing hotspot ap band through shell command

Tags: android

I'm using old Android device(one plus running Android 12.1) as hotspot, it has support for both 2.4ghz and 5ghz band, but one at a time. For a project that I’m doing, I need to be able to switch ap band through shell command

**Things which I think
can help achieve this**

1. I have rooted the phone
2. Macrodroid has shell command capability.
3. [service call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20227326/where-to-find-info-on-androids-service-call-shell-command)

**Question**

1. Even if it’s complicated, I would like to know how to do it without having to simulate ui interaction

**What I've tried**

1. Manual automation through macrodroid, which involves clicking certain areas, and change hotspot settings( but the problem, there are multiple failure points,hence not  reliable, it requires lots of intervention)
2. Tried to find which service let’s you set ap tethering band, checked in IConnectivityManager.aidl, it just sets it to on or off
3. IWifiManager.aidl, has service call to set WiFi band, I think it's to set WiFi band (not hotspot band)