# How can send sms in android in dual SIM with set default sim?

Tags: java, android, sms, message, android-broadcast

How can send sms in android with dual sim for broadcast not intent?? How can detect dual sim in android? User wants to select sim for send sms broadcast. In android set the default sim for sending msg in dual sim in android. User have to select particular sim for sending sms.

Comment: Refer this ... It will help you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517338/android-check-whether-the-phone-is-dual-sim/17499889#17499889

Answer (score 2):

If the output of the shell command '`service list`' contains '`telephony.registry2`', then the phone has a second SIM card. If contains '`telephony.registry3`', then phone has a third SIM card and so on.

You can use [this shell command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17719898/service-call-isms-with-adb-shell-android-sdk) to send from the first SIM card:

```
service call isms 5 s16 "PhoneNumber" i32 0 i32 0 s16 "BodyText"
```

and from the second SIM card

```
service call isms2 5 s16 "PhoneNumber" i32 0 i32 0 s16 "BodyText"
```

Require `android.permission.SEND_SMS`

Comment: How to call in programmatically in android??

Comment: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("service list");` Read manual about Runtime: (http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runtime.html)

Comment: Here is a complete solution for sending and reading SMS for dual sim device for android older than 5... Ihttp://stackoverflow.com/a/30677542/2267723